# Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, cocoa, cocoapods

I run pod install and got this issue on Mac OS M1:

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I haven't received this error for a long time so I can't update now.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Seems it's related to Ruby ffi. Run the following commands:

1. sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
2. arch -x86_64 pod install

Comment: omg it worked, on m1 silicone macbook air. how could u know that :D thanks

Comment: This answer worked for me with a cordova project. I ran the two commands after navigating to my cordova project's ios directory: `cd my-cordova-project/platforms/ios`

Comment: @Roman Dyakonov this command "arch -x86_64 pod install" use Rosseta 2 to emulate pod install ?

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm :)
I'm using Macbook Pro M1 Max.